# Expanders inside listbox leaving blank space on collapse

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, expander

We have a rather complex UI that is presenting some problems for us.

I have a `ListBox` that contains a set of DataItems. The `DataTemplate` for each item is an `Expander`. The header is text, the content of the `Expander` is a `ListBox`. The `ListBox` contains SubDataItems. `The DataTemplate` for each SubDataItem is an `Expander`.

Here is a simplified XAML in which I reproduce the issue:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Header="{Binding Header}">
          <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding SubHeader}">
                  <Grid Height="40">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubText}" />
                  </Grid>
                </Expander>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          </ListBox>
        </Expander>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

There is a problem with how the layout is produced. If any `Expander` corresponding to the SubDataItem is expanded, the `ListBoxItem` containing this `ListBox` (the `Expander.Content` in the parent `DataTemplate`) correctly requests more space. So I can expand all SubDataItems and correctly see my data. However, when I collapse, the space I previously asked to expand, remains blank, instead of being reclaimed by the `ListBoxItem`.

This is a problem because if I have say 10 SubDataItems and happen to expand all of them at the same time and then collapse, there is a significant amount of white space wasting my real estate.

How can I force WPF to resize the `ListBoxItem` to the correct state?

Comment: Why not just use a TreeView / HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: The simplification above describes in essence how our system is implemented. Switching it over to anything else is not an option at the moment. Appreciate the comment though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `DockPanel` as your root's `ListBox`'s `ItemsPanel`, and have each `Expander`'s  `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a ListView, and this solution worked perfectly.